# Storybook: How to annotate generic args/props types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, storybook, tsx

**Context & Code**

We extended our button like so:

```js
export type ButtonProps<P = Record<string, unknown>> = P & {
  children: ReactNode | string
  onClick?: () => void
  className?: string
  disabled?: boolean
  secondary?: boolean
}

const Button = <P extends Record<string, unknown>>({
  children,
  onClick,
  className,
  disabled = false,
  secondary = false,
}: ButtonProps<P>) => {
  ...
}
```

This overloading means we can implement new buttons with additional props, without messing with the original button, à la:

```js
const FooterTwoButtons = ({
  secondaryOnClick,
  secondaryIconType,
  icon,
  className,
  ...props
}: ButtonProps<TwoButtonsProps>) => {
  return (
    <div className={clsx('grid grid-cols-5', className)}>
      <Button onClick={secondaryOnClick} secondary>
        {(secondaryIconType !== undefined && (
          <Icon type={secondaryIconType} />
        )) ||
          (icon !== undefined && icon)}
      </Button>
      <FooterButton {...props}>{props.children}</FooterButton>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It's super nice as it allows more ephemeral button components to be extended from our base type. Everything compiles and works as expected, except for storybook...

**Problem**

I cannot seem to find any questions/issues of a modern storybook component allowing for generic props.

`ExtendedButtonProps` story:

```js
export const ButtonExtendedProps: ComponentStory<typeof Button> = ({
  secondaryIconType,
  children,
  ...props
}: ButtonProps<ExtendedProps>) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button secondaryIconType={secondaryIconType} {...props}>
        {children}
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}
ButtonExtendedProps.args = {
  ...Default.args,
  secondaryIconType: 'CircledX',
}
```

Here is the tsc compiler error, which appears on `ButtonExtendedProps` in the above code:

```js
module ButtonExtendedProps
const ButtonExtendedProps: ComponentStory<(<P extends Record<string, unknown>>({ children, onClick, className, disabled, secondary, }: ButtonProps<P>) => JSX.Element)>
Type '{ ({ secondaryIconType, children, ...props }: ButtonProps<ExtendedProps>): JSX.Element; args: Partial<Record<string, unknown> & { children: ReactNode; onClick?: (() => void) | undefined; className?: string | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; secondary?: boolean | undefined; }> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentStory<(<P extends Record<string, unknown>>({ children, onClick, className, disabled, secondary, }: ButtonProps<P>) => Element)>'.
  Type '{ ({ secondaryIconType, children, ...props }: ButtonProps<ExtendedProps>): JSX.Element; args: Partial<Record<string, unknown> & { children: ReactNode; onClick?: (() => void) | undefined; className?: string | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; secondary?: boolean | undefined; }> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ArgsStoryFn<ReactFramework, Record<string, unknown> & { children: ReactNode; onClick?: (() => void) | undefined; className?: string | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; secondary?: boolean | undefined; }>'.
    Types of parameters '__0' and 'args' are incompatible.
      Type 'Record<string, unknown> & { children: ReactNode; onClick?: (() => void) | undefined; className?: string | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; secondary?: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ButtonProps<ExtendedProps>'.
        Property 'secondaryIconType' is missing in type 'Record<string, unknown> & { children: ReactNode; onClick?: (() => void) | undefined; className?: string | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; secondary?: boolean | undefined; }' but required in type 'ExtendedProps'.ts(2322)
```

Can anyone spot what I've missed here? Is there a page in the storybook docs which provides examples of this? I looked around quite a bit today, but not sure which keywords to search. Any tips are much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it would happen, `ComponentStory<typeof Button> === Story<ButtonProps>`

So the resulting story signature looked like:

```js
export const ButtonExtendedProps: Story<ButtonProps<ExtendedProps>> = ({
  altIconType,
  altClassName,
  altAriaLabel,
  children,
  clean,
  ...props
}: ButtonProps<ExtendedProps>) => {
```